# Adherent point and limits

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Terence Tao Analysis I. I am confused in his remark 9.3.11. Can someone clarify this comment. If someone could also give me an example of a set that doesn't have any adherent point (This is probably[I don't understand remark 9.3.11 given in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q76Bv.png) where the confusion arises)?

Comment: Say you have a function defined only on $\mathbb{Z}$. Does it really make sense to talk about limits? Can you get within say $1/2$ of a point in $\mathbb{Z}$, while staying in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding Tao. What he is saying is that he will not defined $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ when $x_0$ is not an adherent point of $X$. For instance, if $X=[0,1]$, he does not define the meaning of $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)$ (note that $2$ is not an adherent point of $[0,1]$).

Comment: why doesn't he define it ? Is the statement automatically vacuous?

Comment: Not at all! It's because if he had defined it as he did but without the restriction that $x_0$ is an adherent point of $X$, then, when $x_0$ is *not* an adherent point of $X$, then the equality $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ will hold for *every* real number $L$.

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Comment: Take *any* function $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$. I will prove that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=\pi$. Take *any* sequence of elements of $[0,1]$ which converges to $2$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\pi$. That's clear, since there is *no* sequence of elements of $[0,1]$ which converges to $2$.

Comment: That is very clear. Thank you!

Comment: José Carlos Santos: Regarding your example of the function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, I think since there is no sequence of elements of $[0,1]$ which converges to 2 so that the sequence $f(a_n)$ does not exist so I think it is not true to claim that $lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = \pi$ (because the sequence does not exist so it does not make sense to say anything about its limit)

Answer (score -1):

An adherent point to a set is either an accumulation point or an isolate point.

If $ a$ is isolate , then we cannot define $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ .

For example, if $ D_f=E=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$, then $ 2$ is adherent but not an accumulation. So, it is not intetesting to speak about $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$.

Each element of a set is adherent to this set. Every non empty set contains adherent points.